# Implicit conversions in C++

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

Given the following code, why doesn't the compiler resolve the implicit conversion when constructing `Bar`? That is, construct `Foo` just like `a` was constructed which is (should) then be used to construct `Bar`?

```
#include <string>

class ImplicitlyConvertToChar
{
public:
  ImplicitlyConvertToChar(const char* a_char)
    : m_string(a_char)
  { }

  ImplicitlyConvertToChar(const char* a_char, size_t a_end)
    : m_string(a_char)
  {
  }

  template <typename T_String>
  ImplicitlyConvertToChar(T_String const& a_string)
    : m_string(a_string.begin())
  {
  }

  operator char const * () const
  { return m_string; }

  const char* m_string;
};

class Foo
{
public:

  Foo(const ImplicitlyConvertToChar& a_charLike)
    : m_string(a_charLike)
  { }

  const char* m_string;
};

class Bar
{
public:
  Bar(const Foo& a_foo)
    : m_foo(a_foo)
  { }

  Foo m_foo;
};

int main()
{
  Foo a("this works");
  Bar b("Why doesn't this?");
}
```

Comment: It's part of the standard, implicit conversions can't be chained like that.  You can only have one implicit conversion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not allowed more than one user defined implicit conversion. The `Foo` example involves one, the `Bar` example involves two.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is only allowed to make a single implicit **user-defined** conversion.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast

```
A user-defined conversion consists of: 
    zero or one non-explicit single-argument constructor or non-explicit 
    conversion function calls
```

Constructing `Bar` that way would require two.

Comment: Your opening sentence is not correct. The compiler is allowed to make a single implicit ***user-defined*** conversion. It can perform as many implicit ***standard*** conversion as it likes

Comment: I wish it liked none.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan thanks for pointing out this critical oversight.  Answer updated.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast states that only up to two standard conversions can be performed